# RedirectToAction alternative

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3.

I've wriiten a helper class as follows:

```
public static string NewsList(this UrlHelper helper)
{
     return helper.Action("List", "News");
}
```

And in my controller code I use it like this:

```
return RedirectToAction(Url.NewsList());
```

So after the redirect the link looks like this:

```
../News/News/List
```

Is there an alternative to RedirectToAction?  Is there a better way that I need to implement my helper method NewsList?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually you don't really need a helper:

```
return RedirectToAction("List", "News");
```

or if you want to avoid hardcoding:

```
public static object NewsList(this UrlHelper helper)
{
     return new { action = "List", controller = "News" };
}
```

and then:

```
return RedirectToRoute(Url.NewsList());
```

or another possibility is to use [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) which allows you to write the following (personally that's what I like and use):

```
return this.RedirectToAction<NewsController>(x => x.List());
```

or yet another possibility is to use [T4 templates](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC).

So it's up to you to choose and play.

---

UPDATE:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToNewsList(this Controller controller)
    {
        return controller.RedirectToAction<NewsController>(x => x.List());
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return this.RedirectToNewsList();
}
```

---

UPDATE 2:

Example of unit test for the `NewsList` extension method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void NewsList_Should_Construct_Route_Values_For_The_List_Action_On_The_News_Controller()
{
    // act
    var actual = UrlExtensions.NewsList(null);

    // assert
    var routes = new RouteValueDictionary(actual);
    Assert.AreEqual("List", routes["action"]);
    Assert.AreEqual("News", routes["controller"]);
}
```

Comment: @Darin: I want to try and eliminate as much of the hard coding, that was why I wanted to create a helper method.  Is it possible to use the MVCContrib's way in a helper method like I tried doing above?

Comment: @Brendan, yes, you could simply write an extension method of `BaseController` (the same as MVCContrib's `RedirectToAction<TController>`) which would return the redirect result to the list action of the news controller and then use it inside your controller like this: `return this.RedirectToNewsList();`.

Comment: @Daring: Another thing that I also picked up is on my create news page I have a cancel button.  If the cancel button is clicked then it must go to the List page.  Now in my javascript code I have the following: window.location = '@Url.NewsList()';  With the code you suggested above it does not work properly, when I view source then it looks like this: window.location = '{ action = List, controller = News }';  With my original code it would have looked like window.location = '/News/List';

Comment: @Brendan, sure, please see my update about the extension method.

Comment: @Brendan, as far as your second question is concerned there's also the  `BuildUrlFromExpression` extension method in MVCContrib, so I would write another extension method on the `UrlHelper` class which could be used in javascript this time.

Comment: You also have the possibility to use `window.location.href = '@Url.RouteUrl(Url.NewsList())';`. And to shorten the syntax you could encapsulate it back into the extension method.

Comment: Thanks. Almost there. I want to ask you another favour. It has nothing to do with the question, so I would appreciate it if you could help. How would you write a unit test to test all scenarios with your public static object NewsList(this UrlHelper helper) method? Remember it is a static method. :)  Would you mind udating your code?

Comment: @Brendan, please see my UPDATE 2.

Comment: Thanks Darin.  You have been a real help here.